# Unable to copy newly created and updated file from root and sub folder using xcopy

Tags: batch-file

My code to copy files from source to desitination is

```
set "source=C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\msword"
set "dest=D:\Test"

pushd "%source%" ||(
   echo.Source does not exist&pause&goto EOF)

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
   'dir /A-D /OD /B') Do set "file=%%f"

popd

xcopy /s /d /e "%source%\%file%" "%dest%\"
```

I want to script that copy current date created file and any previous file updated on the same day to other drive folder including with same directory structure. But it should only stored current date and update files ...

Comment: the script looks like an incomplete attempt of porting to BAT from some other shell language. Begin debugging one step at a time, and come back here with more specific questions.

Comment: Script works but it only take updated file from root folder and create empty directiores

Comment: it takes only one file because the copy command is located outside the FOR loop. Instead of `SET FILE=...`, try directly `XCOPY %%f ..`

Comment: for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /A-D /OD /B') Do (
set file=%%f
xcopy /s /d /e "%source%\%file%" "%dest%"
)

Comment: i tried above script but still not working.... it showing error of invalid path.

Comment: dont set file, just directly use %%f

Comment: for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /A-D /OD /B') Do (
xcopy /s /d /e "%source%" "%dest%"
)   but above command copying all the files and subdirectories including older files..

Comment: i want the script to backup the latest file of the paticular day and any older file which has been edited on the same day should be copy to other folder with a same directories structure....... And thanks for answering. –

Answer (score 0):

use **robocopy** instead of xcopy.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx

and then try this

```
 robocopy  "C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\msword" "D:\words" /maxage:1
```

Comment: robocopy  "C:\Documents and Settings\kalim\My Documents\msword" "D:\Test" /s /maxage:1          i have just added /s and it done the magic i really appreciated you for giving me your time  and thanks a lot.. .....